# IONIC : run Android error ( ANDROID_HOME )

Tags: android, ionic-framework, .profile

I want to run my IONIC project on my Android device.

When I try : ionic android run I have this error :

> ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
>   Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

This is my ~/.profile file ( I use Ubuntu )

> export ANDROID_HOME=/home/damien/Android/Sdk
>   export PATH=${PATH}:/home/damien/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/damien/Android/Sdk/tools

When I try : source ~/.profile I do not have no error.

Comment: Try adding those lines to your `.bashrc` file instead of `.profile`

Comment: see this [link](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/) it will be useful for you to solve your problem

Comment: I found something. I used Webstorm terminal but I tried with Ubuntu terminal and it works. I do not undertand why. ( I use .profile file )

Comment: Anil can you give appropriate ans.These link has script